# How can I get swap under control while running Ubuntu 20.04 on virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, swap, memory-usage

I'm having a problem where I can't get swap or memory utilization for Ubuntu under control in a VirtualBox VM.  I use Ubuntu fully on the desktop at home, but at work due to IT some kind of PCI compliance, I have to run it within a windows machine.

Unfortunately, while running Ubuntu 19.10 and now 20.04, first the 13 gigs of memory fills up to 100% (which is fine, i do want to use ram), then the swap starts to fill up.  I can sometimes notice that the swap in system monitor is approaching 100%, it's like having a detonation countdown on my screen, except I can't always predict when it reaches it's detonation point.  When the swap fills up, the system becomes 99.9% unresponsive, and often I have to force reboot the virtualmachine.

I have tried:

Setting the swappiness to 0:
grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
sudo cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
0
```

...to no avail.
Currently I'm relegated to having to reboot at random times about twice a day (unless I forget, then I get stuff frozen in the middle of work, and potentially lose programming work-in-progress).

Here is what my "fresh reboot" `free -m` looks like:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          13693        5947        4791         218        2955        7336
Swap:             0           0           0
```

How can I get a 100% memory use and 100% swap usage freeze under control?

---

Edit:

You're right, I missed that, I don't seem to have any swap configured.

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G   0B   -2

I was going off of a GUI graph that would show swap filling up, but I may have disabled swap already.  I suppose I could try turning swap *back on*.

Comment: vm.swappiness=0 is **always** the wrong setting. `free -m` shows that you have no swap. Edit your question and show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Done, that's interesting, it seems like I don't have a swap configured to be of any size.  I wasn't doing free, as I had added a system monitor graph to my desktop, which it would show as filling up after the memory filled.

Comment: So, did you set vm.swappiness back to 60? Did you have to add that line to /etc/fstab... or what did you do to properly enable swap? Is everything working ok now? Based on your response, I'll put together a formal answer for you. Please start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.